# find all using distinct query in Cakephp

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am newbie in cakephp and trying to implement this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT mobilenO,DATETIME
FROM textmessage;
```

what i am trying right now is this

```
$this->find('all',array(
    'fields'=>array('Message.dateTime', 'DISTINCT Message.mobileNo'),
    'order'=>'Message.idTextMessage DESC',
    'conditions' => array('Message.User_id' => $userid)));
```

It is throwing me errors. I actually want to select only distinct or unique numbers from db. I have added the distinct in my query, but it didnt work.

Comment: Can you share the error it is throwing?

Comment: well i got the problem .. i am answering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have to use distinct first not after 1st column.. dont know why but it works

```
       $this->find('all',array(
        'fields'=>array('DISTINCT mobileNo','dateTime'),
        'order'=>'Message.idTextMessage DESC',
        'conditions' => array('Message.User_id' => $userid)));
```

Comment: it works because your sql (`SELECT DISTINCT foo, bar`) is otherwise invalid (`SELECT foo, DISTINCT bar`) - please accept your own answer =).